# Calling std::~basic_string() in gdb

Tags: c++11, gdb, type-conversion, destructor, stdstring

As per @EvanED in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11311786/890753 I created a gdb command `newstr` to create a new std::string and put it in a gdb convenience variable:

```
define newstr
set ($arg0)=(std::string*)malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call ($arg0)->basic_string()
# 'assign' returns *this; casting return to void avoids printing of the struct.
call (void)( ($arg0)->assign($arg1) )
end
```

It works great:

```
(gdb) newstr $foo "hello world"
(gdb) p $foo->c_str()
$57 = 0xb22e388 "hello world"
```

I use `newstr` in other custom gdb commands, so for tidyness I also created `delstr`:

```
define delstr
call ($arg0)->~basic_string($arg0)
call free($arg0)
set ($arg0)=(void*)0
end
```

It works, but the destructor call produces an annoying message:

```
(gdb) delstr $foo
warning: Using non-standard conversion to match method std::string::~basic_string to supplied arguments
$62 = 0
```

Can I avoid the "non-standard conversion" message?  (I'm using gdb 7.10.)

Comment: Also: In `newstr` I used a "cast to void" trick to prevent gdb from printing the return value from a `call` command.  But the last command in `delstr` is a `set` which always prints the set value.  But I don't want `delstr` to print anything.  Is there another trick I can use to avoid that print?

Comment: Actually what I'd _really_ like is to "unset" the convenience variable, but gdb doesn't have a way to do that -- does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR: Pass `0` to the destructor, instead of `$foo`.

```
define delstr
call ($arg0)->~basic_string(0)
#                           ^
call free($arg0)
set ($arg0)=(void*)0
end
```

---

OK so what is going on... We can first check the signature of a destructor. It indeed takes an integer:

```
(gdb) p ((Foo*) 0)->~Foo
$1 = {void (Foo * const, int)} 0x555555554c00 <Foo::~Foo()>

(gdb) p (('std::__cxx11::string'*) 0)->~basic_string
$2 = {void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > * const, int)} 0x7ffff7b75010 <std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()>

(gdb) ptype Foo
type = struct Foo {
  public:
    Foo(void);
    ~Foo(int);
}
```

**So the "non-standard conversion" warning is about converting a pointer to an integer**, which is indeed non-standard. (The warning has nothing to do with the destructor.)

But for what profound reason do we need to pass an extra integer to the destructor in the first place? Turns out it is … [a *bug*](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8218)  A GCC issue (as of gcc 6.3.0) actually, because the same program compiled using clang (as of clang 3.8.1) does not have that extra `int` argument.

---

One should know that, in the Italium C++ ABI there are actually [three destructors](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#definitions) ([D0, D1, D2](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-special-ctor-dtor)).

GCC has an [optimization `-fdeclone-ctor-dtor`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fdeclone-ctor-dtor) which refactors the common parts of the three destructors into a ["D4" destructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1dcb9548bea50ff8fc2f9c066efc0a7ce4dea36b/gcc/cp/mangle.c#L1875-L1879). This "D4" destructor takes [an extra argument `__in_chrg`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1dcb9548bea50ff8fc2f9c066efc0a7ce4dea36b/gcc/cp/decl2.c#L222) to determine which of D0/D1/D2 is the source, to know whether to call the virtual base destructors.

This "D4" destructor is somehow also used as the canonical destructor declaration of the DWARF symbol generated by GCC. If we check the [GCC issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37237#c1) linked from the GDB bug report, the reason of using "D4" is because the GCC developers didn't want to pick which of D0, D1 or D2 to bless.

And the result is an extra `int` which GDB didn't ignore.

The `__in_chrg` value is `2` when the destructor is capable of "complete object destruction" (D0, D1), and `0` when it is just a "base object destructor" (D2). Since a `std::string` does not have virtual base classes, you should just pass `0` to that argument.

---

Note: I used this program to test against GDB:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string aa;
struct Foo {
        Foo() { std::cout << "Constructing: this = " << this << std::endl; }
        ~Foo() { std::cout << "Destroying: this = " << this << std::endl; }
};
int main() {
        Foo foo;
        return 0;
}
```