# How can I get specific std::map value with indexing while using gdb for debuggin c++ code?

Tags: c++, gdb, stdmap

I use Ubuntu 20.04-LTS with WSL(Windows Subsystem Linux), GDB version is 9.2, and I builded my c++ code with c++11.

I tried to access std::map's value with index in GDB, however GDB showed error message "Invalid  cast".

My code is same for below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::map;
using std::string;
using std::to_string;

int main()
{
    map<string, int> si;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        si[to_string(i)] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cout << si[to_string(i)] << "\n";
    }
}
```

And, in GDB

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ctest...
(gdb) l main
6       using std::map;
7       using std::string;
8       using std::to_string;
9
10      int main()
11      {
12              map<string, int> si;
13
14              for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
15              {
(gdb) l 15
10      int main()
11      {
12              map<string, int> si;
13
14              for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
15              {
16                      si[to_string(i)] = i;
17              }
18
19              for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
(gdb) b 18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2579: file ctest.cpp, line 19.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/lksj/ctest

Breakpoint 1, main () at ctest.cpp:19
19              for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
(gdb) p si["1"]
Invalid cast.
(gdb)
```

How can I access the std::map object value directly with index in GDB?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not in the cards. gdb's ability to interpret C++ containers is quite limited. C++ is just too complicated, and only a C++ compiler can fully understand a C++ program. gdb is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah.. then.. can I get a specific value of map object only in "p si" and I try to find what I want to get?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and.. could you tell me what is the best c++ debugger for ubuntu environment?

Comment: try things like "(gdb) print si" first, to see if and how it prints whole map then look further what the problem is.  GDB has improved ... versions 7+ (and that is like for decade)  your's is 9.x its C++ support is quite good.

Comment: I don't have any other debugger to recommend, and recommendations are not appropriate for Stackoverflow. I always used `gdb` on Linux. `gdb` is available everywhere, so I know that it will always be available no matter which Linux distribution I am using.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks your reply. But I know that already. And that code is just test code. However in my actual code, my std::map object has the number of 10,000 elements.. So I need index based method. Thanks again!

Comment: But index of your map is std::string not string literal. Maybe accepted answer of this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429462/creating-c-string-in-gdb

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you very much! Although your link is not helpful directly for me, but I could find solution in related links! The links are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462860/calling-stdbasic-string-in-gdb?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb. I'm verry happy!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @lksj If you figured out a solution you may want to post it as an answer (click "post your answer" button) so future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first write the below code in the ".gdbinit" file.

```
define newstr
set ($arg0)=(std::string*)malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call ($arg0)->basic_string()
# 'assign' returns *this; casting return to void avoids printing of the 
struct.
call (void)( ($arg0)->assign($arg1) )
end

define delstr
call ($arg0)->~basic_string(0)
#                           ^
call free($arg0)
set ($arg0)=(void*)0
end
```

And then write the below function in your c++ code.

```
void indexing_map( map<string,[type]> & m, string i )
{
    cout << m[i] << "\n";
}
```

Now, all things are ready. You just execute gdb for debugging your code with the

```
newstr $foo [any string of map of the key]
```

For example,

example.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::unordered_map;
using std::string;

void indexing_map(unordered_map<string, int> &m, string i)
{
   cout << m[i] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, int> st_in;
    st_in["1"] = 1;
    st_in["2"] = 2;
    st_in["3"] = 3;

    indexing_map(st_in, "1");

    return 0;
}
```

and gdb

```
(gdb) b 25
Breakpoint 1 at 0x28d6: file ctest.cpp, line 25.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/ctest
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at ctest.cpp:25
25          st_in["3"] = 3;
(gdb) newstr $foo "1"
(gdb) call indexing_map(st_in , *$foo)
1
```