# gdb how to pass a string as an argument to a function (C++)

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a following test function

```
bool test(std::string input)
{
  // do something with input

}
```

I would like to call this function from gdb. How do I pass string as a parameter

```
bool test2(const char* input)
{
  // do something with input

}
```

For this one

```
(gdb) call test2("test")
```

seems to work fine. when I try for test I get the following :

```
(gdb) call test("test")
Cannot resolve function test to any overloaded instance
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11311786/1983398).